# Importing fullPage.js in a view CommonJS way

Tags: javascript, browserify, marionette, fullpage.js

I'm trying to write a simple app structure in Marionette starting from Browserify and Grunt skeleton that I found on Marionette.js website: [Here is the repo](https://github.com/marionettejs/marionette-integrations/tree/master/browserify-grunt).

I haven't used Marionette and Browserify before and I'm not really used to the ES2015 syntax yet.

How can I import a plugin i.e. [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) to use it in a view?

This is my view.js right now:

```
import {Marionette} from '../../../vendor/vendor';
import template from '../../templates/homepage.jst';
export default Marionette.View.extend({
  el: '#app',
  template: template
});
```

I've loaded it with npm, and bundled it in "vendor" already

I'm actually looking for the equivalent of

```
<script src="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js></script>
```

for this view.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is interested...

I solved it like this:

1) I installed [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) via npm. This makes CommonJS incompatible files browserifyable (as it was the *fullPage.js* case).

2) Added to *package.json*:

```
"browser": {
  "fullpage1": "./jquery.fullpage.min.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "fullpage1": { "depends": [ "jquery" ] }
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
}
```

For some reason it would not take my whole path to *node_modules/* folder, so I had to copy the .js file to the root of my project (next to *package.json* and *Gruntfile.js*). **It would be very nice if someone figures out why it's not working for *node_modules* folder**.

3) Added this to the *Gruntfile.js*:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                transform: [
                    ['babelify', {
                        'presets': ['es2015']
                    }],
                    ['jstify']
                ]
            },
            files: {
                './public/app.js': [
                    './app/initialize.js',
                    './jquery.fullpage.min.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I'm adding fullpage.js to the app.js that I'm using in the built project.

4) In the end I added this to the render of my view:

```
import {Marionette} from '../../../vendor/vendor';
import template from '../../templates/homepage.jst';

export default Marionette.View.extend({
    el: '#app',
    template: template,
    onRender: function() {
        $('.fullpage').fullpage();
    }
});
```

And that's all

Comment: I had the same problem re: location of fullpage.js file.  It resolved when I renamed the fullpage.js folder to fullpagejs as a stab in the dark, and then renamed it back.  magic.